# Cannot configure From email in new User Pool

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I am configuring a new Cognito User Pool.  I have a verified email address which I am using, but when I try to create the user pool, I get the following error with no hint as to which parameter is invalid:

```
Cannot configure From email address for default email configuration (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException*'*
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You found a solution yet ? I seem to have the same problem

Comment: Just changed to SES from cognito default and it worked for me..

Comment: I also experienced this issue when using the CDK. A similar SES misunderstanding as mentioned by @samairtimer . See this [github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6768) if you are also using the CDK.

Answer (score 16):

I had same issue, Since I had from email address arn, I removed the from email address it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions here:

1. using SES
2. remove email "FROM email address" to use defaults

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in the comment above, changing to use SES seems to solve this issue. I had exactly same problem and using SES worked.